# how can i touch behind layout in framelayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new in android.I want to make layout same like Etsy application.In my xml layout i have imageview behind the content layout.When the user scroll the content layout will be overlay on the imageview.I was put other layout with same size with imageview but i can't touch imageview .How can i touch the behind layout(ImageView) in this situation.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sl"
    android:gravity="center" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/demo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#345343"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#123456"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="50dp"
                android:text="@string/hello_world" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

The ideal same like this :

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3d1o4a93qwm4bjn/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-09%20at%2018.50.22.png 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rc9p8tgdsh17hyq/Screen%20Shot%202014-03-09%20at%2018.50.15.png

Comment: please clear you question. what you want do?

Comment: Sorry for my ideal...My English is very bad. Sometime it not clearly

Answer (score 0):

Set Layout "clickable" attribute value as "false"

```
android:clickable="false"
```

I hope it will works for you.